# Put Azure Key Vault value in parameter array

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I am trying to deploy a App service webapp via ARM template and need to put a secret from a key vault into an app setting (env variable).

I have always simply used an array of values from a parameters file to populate these app settings, but now I am struggling to get a keyvault value into that array. Something like shown below in an ARM parameter file.

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "someStringParam": {
        "value": "stringLiteralValueHere"
    },
    "envVars": {
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "envVarKeyName",
                "value": "stringLiteralValueHere"
            },
            {
                "name": "KVsecret1",
                "value": ##KEY VAULT SECRET HERE##
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

}

I have tried using a reference to the keyvault for the value but that errors on deployment.

```
{
                "name": "KVsecret1",
                "reference": {
                    "keyVault": {
                        "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault_name>"
                    },
                    "secretName": "secret1"
                }
            }
```

I have also tried using a parameter inside of the parameter file, but that just used the literal string for the value.

```
"parameters": {
    "KVsecret1": {
        "reference": {
            "keyVault": {
                "id": "/subscriptions/<subscription_id>/resourceGroups/<resource_group>/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/<vault_name>"
            },
            "secretName": "KVsecret1"
        }
    },
    "envVars": {
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "envVarKeyName",
                "value": "stringLiteralValueHere"
            },
            {
                "name": "KVsecret1",
                "value": "[parameters('KVsecret1')]"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Is this possible??

EDIT: Adding some detail here.

I am also trying to shoe horn a reference to another resource to get put the app insights instrumentation key into an app setting. Below is what I would like to do, but the copy function needs to use the name of the property and that is dynamic in this case as it changes with the each member of the array from the parameter file.

```
{
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/config",
        "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
        "name": "[concat(parameters('backEndwebAppName'),'/appsettings')]",
        "kind": "string",
        "properties": {
            "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "[reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/',parameters('appInsightsName')),'2020-02-02').InstrumentationKey]",
            "secret1FromKeyvault": "[parameters('secret1FromKeyvault')]",
            "copy": [
                {
                    "name": "envVarsFromParams",
                    "count": "[length(parameters('backEndEnvVariables'))]",
                    "input": {
                        "name": "[parameters('backEndEnvVariables')[copyIndex('envVarsFromParams').name]]",
                        "value": "[parameters('backEndEnvVariables')[copyIndex('envVarsFromParams').value]]"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites', parameters('backEndwebAppName'))]"
        ]

    },
```

Comment: You should probably keep you secret in KV and access it suing key vault reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli

Comment: @Thomas That is exactly what I am trying to do, but I need the secret in an array in the parameter file. How do I reference the keyvault secret within an array inside of another parameter?

Comment: butt hen from your sample, it doesnt look like you re using app service key vault reference synthax at all ? The syntax for the secret value should be something like this: `@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret)`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible today within the param file, but in your scenario (if it's as simple as your OP example) you can just union the two in your template.  So in your parameter file, you have 2 params `kvSecret` (the reference) and `envVars` (all your other env vars) and then in the template use:

```json
"variables": {
  "keySecretObj": {
    "name": "kvSecret",
    "value": "[parameters('kvSecret')]"
  },
  "envVarsFinal": "[union(parameters(variables('kvSecretObj`), parameters(`envVars`))]"
```

That help?

Comment: That does help a bit. But it is never that easy is it. I am also trying to shoe horn in a refrence to another resource to get the app insights instrumentation key. Unforgettably I cant put the reference in variable to create that array as a variable for use. I will update my post with some more details

Comment: I think you should be able to do the ```union()``` on the properties body itself, rather than in a var.  That union would then have to contain some inline json in the parameters (which is funky but possible).  The copy loop would have to move to a var.  Another option would be to use a nested deployment to do some "math" to create the app settings - a bit more involved but should let you create whatever you want...  If any of that sounds appealing we might be able to mock something up...

Comment: Yeah thank you for your input. I basically ended up concatenating three things. 1. The array from the parameters file. 2. A dynamically built array which gets secrets from the keyvault via parameters and 3. a createarray method, with the reference to the appinsights intrumentition key. 


"appSettings": "[concat(parameters('backEndEnvVariables'),createArray(createObject('name', 'APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY', 'value', reference(concat('microsoft.insights/components/',parameters('appInsightsName')),'2020-02-02').InstrumentationKey)),variables('keyVaultAppSettings'))]",